# Looking for a book (possibly a pair of them) with whimsical illustrations of misheard phrases

Tags: identification-request

I think I read this at one of my grandparents in the early 1980s, but unfortunately, many of those books have been lost over the years between sticky-fingered grandchildren, general wear and tear, and my surviving grandparents trying to reduce their footprint. I want to say it was two books, probably under 50 pages, hardback, both by the same author. It was a series of misheard phrases in the form of sentences, sometimes a single page and sometimes a two page spread, over a beautiful illustration (I want to say watercolors) of what a child might think they hear. Ones that have stuck with me over the year was one with the mother having a "frog in her throat", showing said frog peeking its head out of her mouth, one where they talk about their family having a "coat of arms" with the illustration showing them opening a closet with a coat covered in arms. There were at least two entries involving a confusion between "prince" and "prints", one involving a "blue prince", one with the "foot prince in the snow". I know there were more, but those are the ones that are coming to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And, of course, right after I post my question, a few further searches found the books. *[The King who Rained](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/616032.The_King_Who_Rained)* and *[A Chocolate Moose for Dinner](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/270411.A_Chocolate_Moose_for_Dinner)* by Fred Gwynne are the books I was looking for. The key came when I started searching for combinations of the phrases I remembered and came upon [this page](https://missfernandez.wordpress.com/about/) which was discussing using it for a lesson plan on homonyms.

> Phrases from the book: (Will be in a handout)
>   A king who rained for forty years
>   Forks in the road
>   A mole on his nose
>   Lambs gamble on the lawn
>   A frog in her throat
>   A little hoarse
>   I’m a little deer
>   Hold up her train
>   Two coats
>   A head on beer
>   Big Bills
>   Play Bridge
>   Coat of Arms
>   Live in the present
>   Bear Feet
>   Foot Prince in the snow
>   Blue Prince for the new room of our house
>   Boars coming to dinner
>   Fairy Tails

They didn't mention the title of the book, but I tried the first term and that brought me to a page on Gwynne's book.